# How can I get power to this garage?

Tags: electrical

What options are there for getting power to this garage?

[image]

The pale grey stuff is concrete, and the flags have been recently cemented down so am keen to avoid pulling them up if possible.

Have seen cable strung overhead in the past. Is this an acceptable solution, and if so how should it be made safe in terms of armour / conduit?

The main need is for lights, so solar power may be an option, although a mains feed would be useful.

Appreciate it would have been a good idea to think of this before laying the flags...

Comment: for cables strung overhead it is usually a steel cable that is strung the weight and the power cable is supported by that cable using a metal spiral.

Comment: Do you need any shielding around it, or is just outdoor grade cable OK to use?

Comment: Doesn't look that far. Depending on the size of wire being used, you might be able to string up an overhead cable without a messenger.  Check with your local building department, they might have some documentation about how to safely feed a detached garage with an overhead feeder. You'll have to be concerned with clearances under and around the cable, support at each building, and possibly support of the cable itself. You'll likely also have to think about grounding and bonding of the second structure.

Comment: They make cables and wires that are designed for this type of thing, so you'll not have to worry about conduit or anything to protect the cable/wires. Since I'm in the US, that's about all the useful information I can provide.

Comment: See http://www.diybasics.co.uk/getting-electrics-garage.html

Comment: Running the conductors in conduit [ both rated for such use ] is an option for an overhead service.